# I can't see faces on every model

Tags: faces

Every time I enter edit mode, I don't see faces at all, just vertices. And that happens on every object/model. How can I fix that?

Btw I'm an absolute beginner.[image]

Comment: Try ALT + H in edit mode ?

Comment: Doesn't make any difference :/

Answer (score 0):

You've just gotta switch to face select by  clicking on it or pressing the number 3, but not numpad 3.

[image]

Comment: I've switched but still, there are no lines that make that "squared" shape. 
Thank you anyways, appreciate it!

https://imgur.com/a/fyz5SFT